# get data in angular4 with services

Tags: angular

I'm new with angular 4 , and I try get data in angular4 , but I get this error . `Cannot get customer.json 404 not found` . I'm think this url is correct , because customer services and customer.json in same folder . Here is my code I tried.

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http , Response} from '@angular/http';

const URL_CUSTOMER = './customer.json'

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    constructor(private _http : Http) {}

    getCustomer(){
        return this._http.get(URL_CUSTOMER)
                .map((response:Response) =>response.json());
}



}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {CustomerService} from '../customer/customer.service';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'customers',
    templateUrl: 'Customers.html',
    providers:[CustomerService]
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
    customers:Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(private _customer : CustomerService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.customers = this._customer.getCustomer();
    }
}
```

main ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Please show me where is my wrong. Thank in advance

Comment: Since your `json` files are external resources (static files), you need to make sure it was actually served by your server.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: @CozyAzure I'm use quick start in angular.io and it no have server

Comment: Try and give the url the complete path, starting from top level folder, which is usually `src`. If that doesn't work, try and set the JSON file in `assets` folder.